# ORA:009955 error(Name is used by an existing object)

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name already used by an existing object in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259351/name-already-used-by-an-existing-object-in-vba)

I am using Oradynaset object to fetch the results from data base in VBA but the same object i.e OraDynaset does not work to create new table as i use the following query

strsql="create table abs.test as (select * from emp)"
Oradynaset=objDatabase.DBCreatedynaset(strsql,o&)

after running this query i get the error - ORA 009955:Object is used by an existing object.

can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create/alter/drop databases and tables(ie. DDL), you should use the ExecuteSQL function of Objectdatabase object.

Oradynaset function of obdatabase objectis used for executing DML command in case of which it stores the fetched result that can be used later by looping through it.

Try by using object database object with sql query as parameter